# Monogame for windows 8 is giving error

Tags: windows-8, monogame

how to use monogame in platform not having directx 11? I tried installing the directx software on my machine but it still is giving some errors. Does anybody has any idea related to this?

Comment: Including the errors would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Same problem was with me but i tried installing the mono again and the problem solved .Do try to install the older versions of the adirectx and sharpdx of old files .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the errors you are getting, but I would ask only how are you installing MonoGame?

The MonoGame guys have added an installer that helps to ensure that you get all the necessary files need to run MonoGame, as well as, install the base templates.  You can find the MonoGame 3.0 installer here: http://monogame.codeplex.com/releases/view/96421

If you need more detail on installation, check out my tutorial here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tarawalker/archive/2012/12/04/windows-8-game-development-using-c-xna-and-monogame-3-0-building-a-shooter-game-walkthrough-part-1-overview-installation-monogame-3-0-project-creation.aspx